# Automatically get "withCount"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I know that you can automatically retrieve relationships by putting the following in a model class:

```
protected $with = [
    'users', 'scores'
];
```

But is it possible to do the same with "[withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)"?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
protected $withCount = [
    'users'
];
```

Comment: Apparently, there's no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the count number of a related model included in the array form output, you have to first create an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) and put it in the `$appends` array of the model.

---

1. Define the accessor

   ```
   //  In your model
   public function getUserCountAttribute() {
       $users = $this->users;    //  From the relationship you defined
       return $users->count();
   }
   ```

   You can now use `userCount` attribute in your object.

---

2. Add the `userCount` attribute to the `$appends` array in the model class

   ```
   //  In your model
   protected $appends = ['userCount'];
   ```

Comment: It would be better to `$this->users()->count()` instead of `$this->users->count()` because the first does it all in one query but the second one loads every related user then counts them.

Comment: This is not true. Calling related models by method `->users()` or by attribute `->users` both return the `Collection` of related objects **assuming you have already loaded the corresponding relationship of that object**. The `->count()` method is provided by the `Collection` class so calling `->count()` is not querying against the database but instead just counting the number of items in the `Collection`. The only difference between them is that if you have not yet loaded the relationship, `->users` will return `null` but `->users()` will immediately query the related objects from database.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php). This is what a relationship method returns. You can see that it holds a query, and all methods called on `->users()` will be run as a query, not on the collection.

Comment: Oh I have made a very horrible mistake. @ntzm is right on the return of `->users()`. This method returns a `Relation` object and at this time the query is not fired to the database yet.

Comment: But since the OP has already added the relation `users` into the `$with` array, a redundant query will be fired to the database if we use `$this->users()->count()` here. We should make use of the loaded collection in the model to get the count number. So `$this->users->count()` is still my choice. :P

Comment: OP said you *can* use `$with`, not that he *is* using it. Anyway I'm being really pedantic and there's probably no noticeable difference anyway in terms of speed and memory footprint.